# Angular UI bootstrap modal fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

Hi I have modal with custom size:

```js
var dialog = modal.open({
                    template: content,
                    size: size,
                    
                    controller:'someController'
                    controllerAs: 'dialog'
                });
```

```css
.modal-custom-lg {
    width:90%;
    max-width:1200px;
      height:100%;

}
```

The width works fine but the height does not work. I am trying to make my modal fullscreen. Can anyone suggest me how to make my modal fullscreen?

Comment: have you try 100vh?

Comment: yes i tried but it did not work

Comment: min-height:100vh!important;, that works for me

Comment: it seems like my modal is inheriting the height of its parent ui grid. Do you know any work around way?

Comment: width:100%;
  bottom:0;
  top:0;
  height:100vh;
  position:absolute; , that should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
.modal-custom-lg .modal-dialog {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.modal-custom-lg .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: where did you put modal-custom-lg class?

Answer (score 1):

So I have to adjust the modal-dialog and modal-content as well not just modal size

```css
.modal-custom-lg .modal-dialog {
  
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    
}

.modal-custom-lg .modal-content {
  
    width: 100%;
   
    height: 100vh;
 
}
```

Comment: Be careful when using 100vh for the height, it may go over the viewport of ios safari.